# How I can restrict access to files with htaccess from all IPs except one?

Tags: .htaccess

How I can restrict access to files with htaccess from all IPs except one?
I want to restrict access from all IPs to php files expect one IP
I mean I want to allow 192.168.1.200 to see php files and Others IPs restrict to see php files
And also Other IPs should access to see other file types like images

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If IP is not 192.168.1.200
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^192\.168\.1\.200$
# block access to all .php files
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: hello @anubhava, what does a backslash mean at the beginning?

Comment: If you mean `\.php` then it is a regular expression where dot needs to be escaped ti avoid matching any character.

Comment: ah my bad! Thank you @anubhava !

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Allow from 192.168.1.200
</Files>
```

it matches all php files and allows only for the specified ip. you should consider adding a 403-error handler